# Find the file with higher version

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I am working in Linux bash.

I have a directory where I have files like this:

- xpto-10.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-10.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-20.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-30.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-10.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-40.20.30.tar.xz
- xpto-40.20.9.tar.xz

I want to get the latest file version name, which should be xpto-40.20.30.tar.xz.

I am using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set_latest () {
  eval "latest=\${$#}"
}
set_latest xpto-*.tar.xz
echo "The highest-numbered file is $latest"
```

But the result I am getting its xpto-40.20.9.tar.xz

I guess this is because of the number of characters.
How can I get the latest file version name (considering this case)?
Is there a way as well to get only version "40.30.30"?

Comment: If you can use external tools, then how about `ls xpto-*.tar.xz | sort -V | tail -n1`?

Comment: One more thing, is there a way to return this value outside of the script? I'd like to use the result outside of this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting:

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz| sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"  |sort|tail -1|sed -E "s|0([1-9])|\1|g"
```

In more readable way:

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz|\
sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"  |\
sort|\
tail -1|\
sed -E "s|0([1-9])|\1|g"
```

#### Gradual running

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz |
```

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz |sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"
```

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz |sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"|sort
```

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz |sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"|sort|tail -1
```

```
ls -1 *.tar.xz |sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"|sort|tail -1|0([1-9])|\1|g"
```

#### Explanation

##### `ls -1 *.tar.xz`

List all files in current directory with suffix `.tar.xz` . A file name per line.

##### `sed -E "{s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|;s|\.([1-9]\.)|.0\1|}"`

In each file name prefix single digit number with 0

##### `sort`

Sort lexicaly all file names

##### `tail -1`

Get the last file name

##### `sed -E "s|0([1-9])|\1|g"`

Remove 0 prefix from 2 digits numbers in filename

Comment: I am getting no output using this command

Comment: see my addition to answer `gradual running`

Comment: Second line in the gradual running returns nothing

Comment: Found the problem, fixed it. try again.

Comment: It´s working now, thanks. By the way, is there a way to get only the "40.20.30" ?

Comment: thank for sharing, please mark as answer.

Comment: to get the numbers only add  another piped grep : ` | grep -o "[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+"`

Comment: it works. Great stuff and thanks a lot!